# Decomposition of VAR(1) coefficient matrix

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, large-data, matrix-decomposition

Consider the VAR(1) process $X_t = \Phi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t.$

Is there a generally accepted decomposition for the coefficient matrix $\Phi$ that would decrease the degrees of freedom?

My initial thought is to explore a technique akin to factor analysis, but I'm uncertain whether this approach is widely accepted or if there exists a more conventional method for achieving this decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to reduce the degrees of freedom? I think what you mean is you want to reduce dimensionality. You can use e.g. LASSO to reduce the number of parameters to be estimated.

See e.g. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2007.12.004.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently reduced rank VARs are a thing: https://towardsdatascience.com/reduced-rank-vector-autoregressive-model-for-high-dimensional-time-series-forecasting-bdd17df6c5ab